# What determines how much experience you get from a kill?

Tags: diablo-iii

Someone told me that monsters don't give a static amount of experience; if that's true, **what determines how much experience you get from a kill?** What's the exact equation?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  It seems to me that you're asking us to clarify a vague statement made by some other people that as far as I can tell, is just plain wrong.

Comment: Based on the other question, if you started in Act IV as a group of (only) level 1 (+/-4)'s, you *would* earn experience faster "per kill".  You'll have a hard time killing anything however.

Comment: I still don't get it; the only thing not answered in the other question is what the base experience of a mob is (e.g. what is "100%" in XP).  In any event, the *question* there is asking the same thing about  how experience works in disparate groups.  If the *answers* aren't up to snuff that doesn't make this not a duplicate.

Comment: @Nick: The question *there* is asking about how experience works in disparate groups; but the question *here* is not.  Please see the title or question body.  I'm sorry if the first paragraph confused that point, but it's been removed now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two factors that change how much experience per kill is given. These factors modify the base experience of the monster, each monster has a different base experience.

First is the monster level vs your level. This chart is from [Malloy626 on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uabo2/d3_exp_chart_updated_may_29_2012/) (click for larger image) demonstrates the approximate experience gain from monsters in each act and difficulty relative to your level. Malloy626 summarizes that the optimal leveling path is the yellow zone in the chart.

[image: chart]

This is based on the following experience chart (monster level vs character level)

```
char level +10 or more of monster level = 0%
+9 = 1% (+exp effects nullified)
+8 = 5% (+exp effects nullified)
+7 = 15% (+exp effects nullified)
+6 = 30% (+exp effects nullified)
+5 = 45%
+4 = 60%
+3 = 70%
+2 = 80%
+1 = 90%
+0 = 100%
-1 = 115%
-2 = 120%
-3 or less = 125%
```

Second is gear with **+experience** ([example](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/lost-boys)) or **+%experience** ([example](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/perfect-ruby)) per kill. This simply multiplies the amount of experience you get after the level disparity modifier is applied.

Note that nothing else effects experience, including additional party members.

Comment: On a side note, that's a great looking graph.

Comment: This seems to contradict [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67997/2578).  Where did "Malloy from reddit" get his/her information from?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft What part is contradicting?

Comment: @Resorath: *"When I left the game - my former party member got demonstrably more experience per kill, on the exact same monsters."*

Comment: The spreadsheet is based on the experience chart, which seems to agree with [this](http://www.clicktoloot.com/p/combat.html#experience). I have not seen any data regarding increased gains based on player numbers. I would like to see a source on that data instead (it is currently original research).

Comment: So your last paragraph is just a guess, then?

Comment: As of [Diablo 3 Patch 2.3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19859662/patch-230-now-live-8-25-2015#general), `Experience gained, including all sources of Bonus Experience, is now averaged across all players in a party that are eligible to receive experience`.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of experience scales both based on the level difference between your character and the monsters, and also the levels of the other players in your party (if applicable). While I don't have a link to any specific figures on-hand, it sounds like the person you spoke to was referencing the fact that being power-leveled by higher-level friends by grinding on monsters will not give you large experience gains, due to the level difference involved.

There *are* alternative ways that people have used to level lower-level characters quickly, but I believe those all center more around quest completion XP than XP gained from killing monsters.