# Why do I earn more experience than my co-op partner?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-console

My boyfriend and I started playing Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls on our Xbox and noticed that something is wrong with how we gained experience. Even when he killed the monsters and I just stood by and "watched", I was the one leveling up very fast. Has anyone had the same experience?

Comment: Have you clicked on any yellow pools? Do you have any additional +XP gear equipped?

Comment: Everyone in the area should get the +XP from the yellow pools. I'd check for +XP on your equipped gear.

Comment: @Adeese only if they were present on the map when the pool was clicked on. I'm not sure if it's possible to be on different maps at same time on the console version though.

Comment: Are you a lower level than the are?

Comment: No, i took away every +XP equipment ... But the weird thing id that he clicked on the yellow pools and i got all the experience... And we are the same level or better put we were the same level when we started

Comment: [Related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/69938/61395)

Answer (score 6):

Everyone within a certain radius of a kill gets XP, so it doesn't matter whether you're 'putting in the work' or not. How much XP everyone gets is dependent on a number of factors, but the most likely culprit is gear. Have a look at your equipment and see if anything is giving you 'bonus XP on kill'(which is not necessarily 'bonus XP on *your* kill'!).

As @Timelord64 notes, Diablo level curve is exponential: each level requires more XP than the one before it. So if you're significantly lower levelled than your partner, you may find that you gain levels more quickly. Generally the level curve means that the level difference will shrink if players are earning XP at the same rate.

Comment: Perhaps you could go into it a bit more then the comments do? provide insight in to what OP should look for, how this would effect the experience gain etc. It might also be of interest to note that OP will level quicker then a higher level with the same experience, due to higher levels requiring more experience then earlier levels.

Answer (score 4):

This should not happen if you are playing on PC.
Since patch 2.3 experience gained, including all sources of Bonus Experience, is now averaged across all players in a party that are eligible to receive experience.

This might be a bug if you keep receiving different XP amounts.

[Diablo 3 Patch 2.3 notes for PC](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19859662/patch-230-now-live-8-25-2015#general)

Comment: Please note that OP is playing on Xbox. I could not find detailed change log for 2.3.0 on consoles, have you?

Comment: @OrcJMR, http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/18704213359. Very easy to find with a quick google, but doesn't list the XP changes. That said, this does answer the question for PC. Remember, we answer questions for the community, not just OP. While this will not be the approved answer, it will help other users.

Comment: @Timelord64 Yes, I saw that too, but I can't call detailed a list that has items like "and more", "several skill updates" and even a straight up "including (but not limited to)".