# Where is the best place to maximize XP per hour in Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I level up more quickly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67914/how-can-i-level-up-more-quickly)

There are many questions here on Arqade about farming xp to get *ready* for inferno difficulty; this question is not my intent. I am playing a level 60 character either solo or with a friend. In both cases, I/we are able to easily clear any Act in Inferno. I am currently running the entire Act 3 each time I play. I currently have a +25% xp gem in my helm(I know this could be higher, but this will just scale and should not effect the answer).

**My current reasons for playing Act 3**:
    High number of elite packs (for early 75% xp gain) - usually around 25-30 per run
    High Density of normal mobs
    Highest possible item level drops

I am not that interested in farming loot for this question, I am simply talking about xp. I rarely pick up items unless they are lvl 63 rares/legendaries, so I only bank about once per trip.

After running through the Act 3 times, I am averaging about 8-10 million xp an hour.

After my above findings, the question remains: Is the best place to farm xp in inferno Act 3? Should I be playing through the entire Act, or should I be focusing on specific quest/quests of the Act, and then restarting the game? Should I be playing Act 2 or 4?

Comment: I also run act 3 but not all of it.  Usually I just do the keep 1-3 and then arreat crater and azmodan.  Maybe I should give a complete act 3 run a try

Comment: Not a dupe IMO. This question asks for a different facet that requires its own unique research. Leveling up quickly at the Paragon stage is significantly different from the first 60 levels, since "progression" isn't really a thing any more.

Comment: @fbueckert StrixVaria correctly mentioned my original intention. I am looking for inferno leveling only. The post you linked was for a level 40 character. I know "how" to level up quickly (have the +xp gems, get 5 stacks, be efficient in banking). I am for "where" to do this in Inferno primarily

Comment: `I rarely pick up items unless they are lvl 63 rares/legendaries, so I only bank about once per trip.`  I also highly encourage you to pick up ilvl 62/61 rare weapons now that they can have the full set of affixes ilvl 63s can have.  I've certainly found 1k+ dps ilvl 62s with great mods on them.

Comment: @yx. Good point, I forgot they updated those weapons/armour as well. I still think it would only be about 2 banks per trip including those though. (1-2 rares from each elite), (2-4 from bosses).

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this is different from the other question, especially given @pixel's bounty to update it for paragon.

Comment: but pixels update was in response to this question, as you see his edit was also yesterday, why punish Jonny for asking a great question.

Comment: Wow 8 million an hour. That's even possible?

Comment: is that money only or you sell equipment?

Comment: @JimThio Over 8 Million XP an hour. I sell all 61+ rares I get and do not pick up the rest