# When gaining level should we just kill enemies or do quests?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo3

I used MP 10 when leveling and earn 70k per hour. Then I just go back to MP 0 and do quests and do 400k per hour.

However, when paragon levelling most people just kill monster.

Why?

Comment: Answered with: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67914/how-can-i-level-up-more-quickly

Comment: NOT duplicate. That question is general. This question is specific.